# Validation of a linear regression model using R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multiple-regression, validation

I have created a multiple linear regression model with R using `lm` and `glm`. I am using `lm` on a training set and `predict` on a testing set to validate the model. In one test my results are within 80% of what they should be for 80% of the cases. It correlates with 40% for one response variable and with 63% for another response variable (but the response variable with 63% correlation isn't near the actual values of the prediction). I have 53 predicates. What is the probability of that occurring randomly?
I've tried to build an multi-class svm off of the features using the predicates but so far the svm has been unable to properly predict the results.

Comment: You could validate by simulation when the predictors truly have no effect or by permuting the responses to give an idea what prediction accuracy to expect purely by chance.

Comment: @Macro thanks macro i think your pointing towardss cross validation. 
I ran cv.lm with 10 fold cross validation on the datset with 63% corrolation and i found the Sum of squares = 2.91e+08 is Mean square = 1063519 and the data set with 40% corolation has Sum of squares = 23.1    Mean square = 0.08. A low mean square means that it has predictive ability so my main questions is how to i find the the probability of it concurring randomly?

Comment: If you simulate data where the predictors truly have no effect, this will give you a reference. If you permute the response variables, you will also have a situation where the predictors have no effect, so that would be another way of getting a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the binomial distribution assuming the probability of each 10% point is equal falling within 10%+/- of the actual answer is 3/10. From there you take the total number, the amount that fit the criteria and the probability and plug them into this page and you find the number is very small. http://homepages.wmich.edu/~bwagner/StatReview/Binomial/binomia%20in%20excel.htm I'll post this as an answer in a couple of hours.